# Django's static file related issue

Tags: python, django

I don't know why the static file's url is changed in Django's Administration Page.
My model class is like below

```
class MW_test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    tst = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='static/test_images')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

As you can see at above code, static file is saved in `static/test_images`.
But, when I clicked on static file link from Django Administration page.(see below screen shot) I have got 404 not found.(see below screen shot)
The reason is the requested url is not what I had uploaded url. I don't know why the url link changed in Django administration. Actually, when I typed the url in manually, I can get the static file.

[image: Django Administration Page]
[image]

Comment: can you post STATIC_URL in settings.py ?

Comment: If you look at the URL in your stacktrace you'll see that your static url is correct, it's just that you're building the URL wrong within your admin class. You want that link to point to `/static/test_images/....`.

Answer (score 0):

For Local testing and usage the following updates need to be done:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and in settings file add something like:

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT_DIR = 'static-tmp'
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_ROOT_DIR))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR_BASE_PATH = join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_DIR_BASE_PATH,
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: I have no setting about **MEDIA_ROOT** and **MEDIA_URL**, what can be done? what can be set value?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT_DIR = 'media'
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_ROOT_DIR))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_URL` needs to be an absolute path: ie it must begin with a slash. You have probably set it to `static/`: it needs to be `/static/`.